# Imprimir una variable de PHP en código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```js
    <script type='text/javascript'>
//Load the file containing the chat log
    function loadLog(){     
   <?php 
        $usuario =  $_SESSION['name']; // capturo el usuario
        $usuario .=".html"; //concateno el nombre del usuario con .html
        $usuariochat = $usuario;  //le asigno a usuariochat lo concatenado
   ?>
        $.ajax({
            url:<?"$usuariochat"?>, 
//aca es donde tengo el problema, necesito 
que a URL: me le lleve lo concatenado para que me busque ejemplo: 
prueba.html y me traiga la informacion que hay ahi al chat.
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $('#chatbox').html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div
            },
        });
    }
    setInterval (function(){ loadLog() }, 1500); //recargamos la funcion loadlog cada segundo para actualizar el chat.
</script>
```

como ven intento que dentro del ajax, me capture lo que esta en la variable $usuariochat para poder traer toda la informacion que almaceno ahi en el chat.

Que me recomiendan?

Comment: Puedes explicar a qué te refieres con detectar? Intenta aclarar la pregunta y el código, así será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, necesito capturar dentro del javascript la variable que tengo en php. ahi en el codigo comente lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu código. A la propiedad url le estás intentando pasar una variable sin imprimirla.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//Load the file containing the chat log
    function loadLog(){     
        <?php 
            $usuario =  $_SESSION['name']; // capturo el usuario
            $usuario .=".html"; //concateno el nombre del usuario con .html
            $usuariochat = $usuario;  //le asigno a usuariochat lo concatenado
        ?>
        $.ajax({
            url:<?php echo $usuariochat?>, //aca es donde tengo el problema, necesito que a URL: me le lleve lo concatenado para que me busque ejemplo: prueba.html y me traiga la informacion que hay ahi al chat.
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $('#chatbox').html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div
            },
        });
    }
setInterval (function(){ loadLog() }, 1500); //recargamos la funcion loadlog cada segundo para actualizar el chat.
```

Prueba con esto a ver qué tal.

Por cierto, si estás practicando con PHP o JavaScript me parece fantástico. Pero tal vez te interese saber que para chats existen otras alternativas mucho mejores que AJAX y un intervalo de sondeo.

Mírate el protocolo WebSockets. Si quieres darle duro, échale un ojo a XMPP, es el protocolo que usa WhatsApp, tal vez encuentres alguna implementación interesante.

Comment: nada, ya lo habia intentado asi y no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Ya me dio,

```js
url: '<?php echo $usuariochat?>',
```

le agregue las comillas y el echo y funciono.

muchas gracias